# Matplot, how terminate a python script with a second script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python script that runs matplotlib to plot a figure on the screen (with plt.show). I need to launch this script every hour in order to update the pie with last values collected. As matplot is blocking with the previous pie drawn on the screen, I can not draw a new pie with new values.
I need to close automatically the previous plot but only as soon as the script is run again (via cronotab). I tried with a different script to be launched before the re-launch of the plotting script and with plt.close(‘all’) but it doesn’t work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Would it be an option to use a `FuncAnimation` and never close the window?

Comment: I checked FuncAnimation but as per what I understood it takes some resources and I must keep the script always running, that’s not what I want to.

Comment: I don't quite see the difference between stopping the script and restarting it in the very moment or just keeping it running throughout. The latter might even be less resource hungry.

Comment: You’re right, I’ll try animation or even creating a loop with several minutes of interval for my purpose to get update each 60’.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution valid for me. I put the plotting in a while cicle and I put, at the end:

```
plt.show(block=False)  
time.sleep(3600)  
plt.close('all')
```

now it work as expected. The pie is updating every hour, redrawing itself with new values. I know that block=False is deprecated but I tried other solution without success (like plt.ion()).